# spinner for each formula

Tags: android, android-spinner

***I have 3 menu on spinner.***
square, circle, and the right triangle, I want each menu to have a different formula, example

```
a= x*y
b= x+y
c= x:y
```

***The value of x is taken from EditText1,value of y is taken from EditText2.
its output value is in TextView.***

*here is my code:*

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private EditText editText,editText2;
    private Button button;
    private TextView luasbangundatar,kelilingbangundatar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        luasbangundatar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.luasbangundatar);
        kelilingbangundatar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kelilingbangundatar);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String edt1 = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                    String edt2 = editText2.getText().toString().trim();

                    int formula1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1)*Integer.parseInt(edt2);
                    int formula2 = (2*Integer.parseInt(edt1))+(2*Integer.parseInt(edt2));

                    luasbangundatar.setText("Luas Dari Bangun Datar :"+String.valueOf(formula1));
                    kelilingbangundatar.setText("Keliling Dari Bangun Datar:"+String.valueOf(formula2));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

how i can add each formula for every menus from spinner ?
cmiiw

Comment: Wat did you tried with spinner? add some relevant code for spinner..

Comment: I dunno how to implement spinner in here

Comment: I was looking for this trouble on YouTube and google but i cant got it

Comment: have look at this two ways to load spinner data https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: Ok ill check it if im at home, thx b4